# What is the period of the function $f(x)$

Tags: functions

Given:

> $f(x) + f(x+T) = 2$ ; where $T$ is a fixed positive number.

The solution is given as:

> put $x = x+T$
>
> then given equation becomes
>
> $f(x+T) + f(x+2T) = 2$
>
> subtract given equation from above. You'll get: $f(x) = f(x+2T)$.
>
> Hence $2T$ is the period of $f(x)$.

I don't get it. wouldn't putting $x = x+T$ change the value of the function? How come we are still equating it to $2$? If the function value doesn't change then we are implicitly assuming that $T$ is the period right?

Comment: To nitpick, this only shows that $2T$ is *a* period of $f$ (rather than *the* period).  It is possible that there is a smaller period.  E.g., this would hold for $f(x)=1+\cos(x)$, and $T=3\pi$.  Many would regard it as incorrect to say that $6\pi$ is the period of $f$, even though it is true that $f(x+6\pi)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Jonas:  nitpicking encourages precision.  Yours is a good example.  Is the definition of period the smallest period or a period?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition

> $f(x)+f(x+T) = 2$

means that for *every* value of $x$, no matter what it is, if you evaluate $f$ at $x$ and at $x+T$, and add them, then you get $2$. So $f(1)+f(1+T) = 2$, $f(3.5) + f(3.5+T) = 2$, $f(0) + f(0+T) = 2$, $f(y) + f(y+T) = 2$,  etc.

In particular, $f((x+T)) + f((x+T)+T) = 2$, by picking as our value of $x$ the value $x+T$.

This means that for every value of $x$, $f(x) + f(x+T) = f(x+T) + f(x+2T)$ (by substituting the $2$ in "$f(x)+f(x+T) = 2$" by $f(x+T) + f(x+2T)$, which we know is also equal to $2$). This says that for every value of $x$, $f(x)=f(x+2T)$.

Answer (score 3):

For a slightly different solution, you could consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-1$.  Then

$\begin{align*}
g(x)+g(x+T)
&=(f(x)-1)+(f(x+T)-1)\\
&=(f(x)+f(x+T)) -2\\
&= 2- 2 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}$

for all $x$.  This implies that $g(x)=-g(x+T)$ for all $x$, so $$g(x+2T)=g((x+T)+T)=-g(x+T)=-(-g(x))=g(x).$$

Then $f(x+2T)=g(x+2T)+1=g(x)+1=f(x)$.